# Fabric plugin not working with proxy

Tags: google-fabric

I'm currently facing an issue with Fabric plugin(4.1.1) in Android Studio 2.3 where Fabric doesn't seem to work well with a proxy.

To configure the proxy I searched through Fabric documentation's and found this : https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#proxy-setup

I created **idea.vmoptions** and filled it with proxy configuration, but I still can't connect to my account or even fetch Fabric's dependencies.

So I checked the logs in **idea.log** and it says :

> com.crashlytics - Crashlytics could not retrieve proxy settings from IntelliJ 
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PROXY_LOGIN

Since the proxy that I use doesn't needed identification, I added this field in **idea.vmoptions** and leaved it empty but I still get this error.

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I'll have to do more digging on the proxy issue, but you may try to get up and running here instead: https://fabric.io/kits